# Opening shapefile created by ArcMap in QGIS

Tags: qgis, arcmap, shapefile, file-geodatabase

I've recently started working with QGIS after my ArcMap student licence expired. I'm trying to open files in a geodatabase created in ArcMap but most of the files in it are missing (.shp). The program simply doesn't recognize them (though a browse through the file itself shows they are there - not accidentally deleted).

If this is a compatibility problem, then how can I get access to the files in QGIS without using ArcMap?

I now also notice that rasters are not opening and that the files are locked

Comment: You cant (shouldnt!) store shapefiles inside a file geodatabase. Are you sure you have shapefiles inside a file geodatabase and not a file geodatabase with feature classes? Try copy pasting them to a normal folder using windows file explorer then try QGIS again

Comment: It worked partially. I might have been mistaken and have a file geodatabase with feature classes' as you said. when I copied the file elsewhere it showed a few more but not everything I had in there.

Comment: Rasters aren't supported with file geodatabase access APIs. You are unlikely to extract them without access to an ArcGIS license.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't open files directly from the `.gdb` folder.
What you should do is use the `Data Source Manager` and select the GeoDataBase folder, and within it select the layers.

The Process is explained [here](https://arc2qgis.github.io/Basics/import_data.html#fgdb).

You can also see the layers from the browser, the `.gdb` folder appears there like a GeoPackage database.

Comment: This worked perfectly for the feature files, but QGIS still doesn't recognize my DEMs, which are in a different .gdb. any suggestions?

Comment: This will probably be annoying, but maybe convert them with ogr2ogr? I am not entirely sure that rasters within gdb are supported by gdal, which will mean they might not be supported in QGIS.